# mathpazo + siunitx: π turns into ß

Tags: fonts, siunitx, mathpazo

When I use `mathpazo` and `siunitx` (version 2.3h) together, if I use `\pi` inside the numerical argument to `\SI`, it will show up in the output as "ß".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo, siunitx}
\begin{document}
    $\pi + \SI{\pi}{\ohm}$
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: wrong output]

But when I don't use `mathpazo`:

[image: correct output]

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As others have observed, the issue here is the way the `mathpazo` treats `\pi`. I would go with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo, siunitx}
\protected\def\numpi{\text{\ensuremath{\pi}}}
\sisetup{input-symbols = \numpi}
\begin{document}
    $\pi + \SI{\numpi}{\ohm}$
\end{document}
```

The idea here is that this approach forces the use of the 'standard' font for `\pi` in all cases (it's safe in both math and text mode). There are reasons that `siunitx` uses `\mathrm` rather than `\mathnormal` as the standard math mode font: try

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $\mathnormal{123}$
\end{document}
```

to see why!

Comment: Thank you! That all makes sense, except for why `mathpazo` treats `\pi` weirdly inside `mathrm` in the first place in the first place...

Answer (score 8):

The following rectifies your problem:

- `\pi` *without* [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) or [`mathpazo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo) is defined as `\mathchar"119`;
- `\pi` under *only* `siunitx` remains the same (`\mathchar"119`);
- `\pi` under *only* `mathpazo` is defined as `\mathchar"7119`.

Since `siunitx` does not touch the definition of `\pi` and the load order does not correct for this, redefining `\pi` works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,mathpazo}
\begin{document}
  $\pi + \SI{\pi}{\ohm}$ \par
  \renewcommand{\pi}{\mathchar"119}% Revert to original mathchar definition for \pi
  $\pi + \SI{\pi}{\ohm}$ \par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does the output differ between math mode and inside the `\SI` command, with both `siunitx` and `mathpazo`?

Comment: @jtbandes: I am not sure. Perhaps @JosephWright ([`siunitx` maintainer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here)) has some insight on this. This has been raised on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).

Comment: If used regularly inside `\frac{}{}` (not as part of `\SI`), `\pi` does not appear, nor does the subsequent character. I don't know why this happens, but it can be fixed (as I'm sure you would guess) by adding `\relax` after `\mathchar"119` in the definition.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that **mathpazo** defines `\pi` as `\mathalpha`, that is it adds `"7000` to its code *and* that **siunitx** uses by default `\mathrm` in the arguments of `\SI`:

```
\sisetup{number-math-rm=\mathnormal}
```

would be wrong; use

```
\SI[number-math-rm=\mathnormal]{\pi}{\ohm}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous wrong answer. Here is a tested code. It looks more concise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo, siunitx}
\begin{document}
    $\pi + \SI[mode=text]{\pi}{\ohm}$

    $\pi + \SI{\pi}{\ohm}$

    $\pi + \SI[mode=math]{\pi}{\ohm}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: The code will not work if you replace the '\pi' inside the numerical argument by other non-numeric symbols like 'p'.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me. Besides `\mathit{\pi}` seems unlikely to work in `\SI` (unless one turns number parsing off).