# Mathpazo in conflict with amsmath?

Tags: amsmath, greek, mathpazo

When using `\DeclareMathOperator` from the amsmath package and the mathpazo package (for fonts) the greek letters aren't printed correctly.

For example, with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{\pi}

\begin{document}
    $\proj$
\end{document}
```

I should get a pi, but I don't get a pi at all, instead I get an esszet (a german letter that looks like a beta).

Does anyone understand why this happens?

Thanks in advance! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell us, why you are trying to do this? `\DeclareMathOperator` is meant for stuff like sin, cos, Max, Min... The problem you are seeing here appears already for ` $\operatorname{\pi}$`. Depending on what you want to get, I would just go for `\newcommand{\proj}{\pi}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Indeed using `\newcommand{\proj}{\pi}` worked, thanks!
The reason why I used `\DeclareMathOperator` is because I was defined a series of operators with it (most of them like `\DeclareMathOperator{\defrag}{defrag}` and some of them much more simple like `\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{\pi}`

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` is intended to be applied to alphabetic strings.  `\pi` doesn't count as alphabetic, but only as a math symbol, so i'm not surprised that the result is "unpredictable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution elsewhere: by using `\mathchar"119` instead of `\pi` the problem doesn't show up
(cf. [mathpazo + siunitx: π turns into ß](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33140/mathpazo-siunitx-%CF%80-turns-into-%C3%9F) ; I hadn't seen it before)

In this particular case LaRiFaRi's suggestion of using `\newcommand{\proj}{\pi}` works too :) .

Comment: you might want to use `\newcommand{\proj}{\mathop{{}\pi}}` to get the same mathop spacing as other operators

Comment: Yes, that also would keep the spacing that I want without conflicting with mathpazo.
Thanks