# Unable to use greek letter commands in mdpi template

Tags: siunitx, templates, greek, mdpi

I currently try to use the following template

[MDPI_template.zip - contains the template, logo, class and bibliography style files](http://img.mdpi.org/data/MDPI_template.zip?v=20180514)

and I am having trouble using greek letter commands in siunitx (which I added to the template). Is there some conflict that I am not aware of? I appreciate any help.

Minimal example in template:

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex,10pt,a4paper]{Definitions/mdpi} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\tau}
\end{document}
```

translates to

`1 ø`

I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) on MacOs

Comment: MWE for people who don't want to download a custom class: `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\tau}
\end{document}`

Comment: thank you @moewe for adding that MWE and already pointing out the conflict...? Uncommenting `mathpazo` in `mdpi.cls` fixed it. Why the conflict and is there a way of keeping the cls file as it is?

Comment: Actually on second thoughts: What is `\SI{1}{\tau}` supposed to do anyway? AFAICS `\tau` is not a valid unit listed in the `siunitx` manual. AFAIK you can only expect the unit macros listed in §4.4 *The unit macros* of the `siunitx` documentation or self-defined units (`\DeclareSIUnit`) to give proper output. So I would argue that the fact that `\tau` comes out properly with other fonts is just by accident.

Comment: It is supposed to be a so-called internal unit but you might be right and would have to declare it first. It is a "lazy" way of getting the right formatting for it...

Comment: Possibly related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33140/35864

Comment: `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\mathchardef\mytausymb"11C
\DeclareSIUnit{\mytauunit}{\mytausymb}
\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\mytauunit}
\end{document}` might work.

Comment: @moewe I'd say `\DeclareSIUnit{\utau}{\text{$\tau$}}` is easier.

Comment: @egreg I'll take your word for it. I'm not quite sure what exactly is happening here...